# PHP GD header issue

Tags: php, gd

A couple of months ago I enabled GD on localhost to play around with it a bit, used various scripts found online to get a better understanding of what it does, all good and well.

But now I feel like I'm descending into insanity here because when trying to repeat the above with the exact same scripts I keep getting header errors, both on local and remote host. I figure I must have somehow completely forgotten how do do it right so I need a brief refresher on this.

For example, this was the first script I ever tried:

```
$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "thesitewizard.com",
$text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
```

[Source](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/create-image.shtml)

Worked fine back then, now when I run it I get this:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\script.php:1) in H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\script.php  on line 11
�PNG  ��� IHDR�������P���!�#��� PLTE���������M�)B����IDATH��1�0EA��N�����:��8Q�JN�d�Z��`��! � ���k�Z⊜���k��g�˕��|K$�M��|)��$ů8DfRQB���-��[I��tźR�+���%�"��Ut)(�K�@dF�e�zKF9&�g|C7i��d��\G�Y � �3y�Ƌ�_�%�����IEND�B`�

Warning: Wrong parameter count for imagecolordeallocate() in H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\script.php on line 13

Warning: Wrong parameter count for imagecolordeallocate() in H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\script.php on line 14

Warning: Wrong parameter count for imagecolordeallocate() in H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\script.php on line 15

Same thing for the second script I ever tried:

```
// create a 200*200 image
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 200);

// allocate some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$red   = imagecolorallocate($img, 255,   0,   0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($img,   0, 255,   0);
$blue  = imagecolorallocate($img,   0,   0, 255);

// draw the head
imagearc($img, 100, 100, 200, 200,  0, 360, $white);
// mouth
imagearc($img, 100, 100, 150, 150, 25, 155, $red);
// left and then the right eye
imagearc($img,  60,  75,  50,  50,  0, 360, $green);
imagearc($img, 140,  75,  50,  50,  0, 360, $blue);

// output image in the browser
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);

// free memory
imagedestroy($img);
```

[Source](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.imagearc.php)

That now outputs:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\script.php:1) in H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\script.php  on line 22
�PNG  ��� IHDR�����������":9���gIDATx����v�H�a<�4Ƹ���ܕ��:/{�v�}��z����C��(�~��҆�Uj1�jƖ�~)y[�x��JW��+/n�q�9)eɽ?�n�q%Pfg��f� �s+��I޽;I��l ��2s��-R����u 9���b�}��H�d�B�v��R��2��Kr�h�u�v�8���y�U��|��^O�T�'�:��I *R!��r�%���Z����$_�L�ʴVd�W�U�'��tk��2\�XA�5�s���ϔGL0�*Q���:0O|M�W� ����j�ܼC��*�U}�՚���FŹǂ�UO�֝���ά�OW�z�k���N"��� ���1F��"ls{r�?�@��/v���ZSw1i���? i�8�]��C��A��xN?xw�죙��ۮ�9 -&�C�h�N���"r��B��!����`��j�Ǹ�_"ե>�Љ�u��q����9ɫ�T��5�s0*���*xݣ> �X!�w�����R�u �~�-O7�"�� <��·v���K��i�;�Dv��c��P�q��h,)~C��w���`��9��<��N�!&h,���`����q�5���v&h,���`���&��k��X\'��7�l�F�.�-�B���`�Ƃ�ğ'� ^Ajw�1�X0��X"�*��z�.�&"+|{��v/a+0�1o�i0G!l�~�o�+_�� �_��� 8�r|��F���k��!������}>��Ǟ7Xbb=�]�Rd��1��f�d�}�Nـ�k�ۉ���[5�k��6��y��I��jc�~/��˭N�ڍ�� �s�����4L�X0Ac��4L�X0����;�a�Ƃ &h,���`�Ƃ%�q�,�Nh,���`�Ƃ1���=�V�h,���`��,|c�?L,���`�Ƃn�pϮs<&��ơ"��bq2�tX��w�0��h��bb�^����4�¿�+���; �p1�\�_����ܶ�\o�Z�$����Yxz˟Q�O:��`"��8� �Ov���|���78 ���WԸZ�X����(p\=����? y�a:��N���ޚ�4��{ ~b��[S$�UO��ᡷ�a�=��[���=֩��Z_6����w��|�}�CBf"�K�$${��3�E^�vMϨc$ڻ��f�Pu+W�+��;{�L �6Dލ�w�G������J��۪��T�c�rl��n_J�E]�|��m����}���an>���Խ����IEND�B`�

However, the third script I ever tried still works:

```
// read the post data
    $data = array('100','200','300','400','500','350','270');
    $x_fld = array('Sun','Mon','Tue','Wen','Thu','Fir','Sat');
    $max = 0;
    for ($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
      if ($data[$i] > $max)$max=$data[$i];  // find the largest data
    }
    $im = imagecreate(320,255); // width , height px

    $white = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255); // allocate some color from RGB components remeber Physics
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0);   //
    $red = imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,0);   //
    $green = imagecolorallocate($im,0,255,0); //
    $blue = imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,255);  //
    //
    // create background box
    //imagerectangle($im, 1, 1, 319, 239, $black);
    //draw X, Y Co-Ordinate
    imageline($im, 10, 5, 10, 230, $blue );
    imageline($im, 10, 230, 300, 230, $blue );
    //Print X, Y
    imagestring($im,3,15,5,"Students",$black);
    imagestring($im,3,280,240,"Days",$black);
    imagestring($im,5,100,50,"Simple Graph",$red);
     imagestring($im,5,125,75,"by Vijit",$green);

    // what next draw the bars
    $x = 15;    // bar x1 position
    $y = 230;    // bar $y1 position
    $x_width = 20;  // width of bars
    $y_ht = 0; // height of bars, will be calculated later
    // get into some meat now, cheese for vegetarians;
    for ($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
      $y_ht = ($data[$i]/$max)* 100;    // no validation so check if $max = 0 later;
      imagerectangle($im,$x,$y,$x+$x_width,($y-$y_ht),$red);
      imagestring( $im,2,$x-1,$y+1,$x_fld[$i],$black);
      imagestring( $im,2,$x-1,$y+10,$data[$i],$black);
      $x += ($x_width+20);   // 20 is diff between two bars;

    }
    imagejpeg( $im, "graph.jpeg", 90);
    imagedestroy($im);
    echo "<img src='graph.jpeg'><p></p>";
```

[Source](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4619.html)

It seems that the fact it doesn't output a header is why it works, though why the others used to work and now don't are beyond me, especially since the errors are also being replicated on an unrelated remote host, am I simply being clueless and calling the scripts erroneously? And before anybody asks, yes, I'm sure GD has been fully enabled, here are the relevant specs from phpinfo:

**GD Support:   enabled

GD Version:     bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

FreeType Support:   enabled

FreeType Linkage:   with freetype

FreeType Version:   2.1.9

T1Lib Support:  enabled

GIF Read Support:   enabled

GIF Create Support:     enabled

JPG Support:    enabled

PNG Support:    enabled

WBMP Support:   enabled

XBM Support:    enabled**

Can someone please enlighten this befuddled girl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is very simple (apart from the warnings about imagecolordeallocate()).

**You need to encode and save your script file as `UTF-8 withuot BOM` or `ASCII`. It is currently saved as `UTF-8` which is causing the problem** due to the extra BOM character.

The [`BOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) character in UTF-8 encoded pages messes up the output as it is sent as the first character. BOM use is optional, and, if used, it appear at the start of the text stream.

Use any advanced text-editor or IDE like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to encode the script file and save it.

Comment: You are correct, I changed the scripts' encoding to UTF-8 withuot BOM and they all work flawlessly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any whitespace in your file (probably outside of `<?php ... ?>` tags)? Any stray whitespace will be sent to the client, after which headers can no longer be sent. Based on the line number in your error message, there probably is whitespace before your opening `<?php`, so ensure that it is the first thing in the script.

Also, from your error messages, you can see that you're calling [`imagecolordeallocate`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolordeallocate.php) with the wrong number of parameters. The first argument is supposed to be your image handle, so the correct call would be

```
imagecolordeallocate($my_img, $line_color);
imagecolordeallocate($my_img, $text_color);
imagecolordeallocate($my_img, $background);
```

The error messages being outputted would also be sent to the client which would prevent headers from being set.

Answer (score 1):

it's not header problem.
It's Wrong parameter count for imagecolordeallocate() causing whole mess
While this one is plain and clear.

Comment: First code block has the parameter count issue, second code block doesn't have that error - not the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check there's no whitespace before you open your PHP tags, as this would put the server into text/html mode.

EDIT: Ah yeah, scratch that. It's what Col. Shrapnel said. The error is forcing the page into text/html.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, some thing is getting output from the file H:\xampp\htdocs\tests\script.php on line 1

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is path of folder 
 Create a folder for image for example.:  barla

After change your header
header("Content-type: barla/image/png");